# texture wrapping is not repeating as it should be

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to wrap a texture for the floor, but it doesn't work - the texture is not repeated 5 times as it should be. Here s the code I used:

```
var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/floor.jpg' );
floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
floorTexture.repeat.set( 5, 1 );
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 45, 44.5 );
var floor = new THREE.Mesh( floorGeometry, floorMaterial );
```

You can see the project here : http://provasitimek.herobo.com/Tesi9.2/ - choose the userGroup, then the paths, the startPoint end the endPoint to visit the model

Comment: Is you image a power of 2?

Comment: In which of all those js files in you example is the relevant code?

Comment: no, the image is not a power of 2, is 800x1200 pixels; Why? is this relevant? the code above is on http://provasitimek.herobo.com/Tesi9.2/jsLib/functions_init.js in the function initFloor

Comment: Scale it to 1024x512 and see what happens. WebGL only supports powers of 2.

Comment: thx a lot, now works perfectly. If you repost those comments as an answer, I will flag it as accepted

Comment: my image is power of 2 but it still didn't work... i followed the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that your texture has sizes which are power of two.

Generally WebGL does not support NPOT (non-power of two) textures. There are some exceptions though outlined at [Non power of two textures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Using_textures_in_WebGL#Non_power-of-two_textures)