# texture not applied properly with Three.js

Tags: three.js, textures, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I work with Forge Autodesk, and I want to apply a texture to some rectangle object. In fact I just needed some plan, but I was given a rectangle. So I want to apply my image on the main face of the rectangle.

```
const mytex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(mytexture)

// Repeat image through object

mytex.wrapS  = THREE.RepeatWrapping   //ClampToEdgeWrapping  //MirroredRepeatWrapping   //RepeatWrapping
mytex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping    //ClampToEdgeWrapping   //MirroredRepeatWrapping   //RepeatWrapping
mytex.mapping = THREE.UVMapping
mytex.repeat.set (0.05, 0.05)

console.log("applied texture")
```

But I get this problem : a part of my image appears on the right upper side (upper and right corners are cut, so not on the rectangle), but the left and bottom sides are stretched across the rest of the rectangle face.

I would like to adapt my image so that its dimension fit the rectangle's dimensions, and not just repeat it.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587333/three-js-texture-not-repeating-properly) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100481/texture-wrapping-is-not-repeating-as-it-should-be). I think my code is correctly written, but I may be missing a parameter or set the wrong one...  The 2 images I am testing are 676x676 and 1024x484 pixels. I cannot access the rectangle dimensions from my function (I don't think so).

I tried to just repeat the image too but it does not work either...

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you post a bit more code, so we don't have to assume what kind of geometry you are working with ... the more info you provide in your question the easier it will be for somebody else to jump in and help you